# I want to select the range of dates in calendar

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```dart
Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context, List<String> parsedDate1) async {
    final DateTime? pickedStartDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: startDate ?? DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2000),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime date) {
        // Add your logic for selectable dates if needed
        return true;
      },
    );

    if (pickedStartDate != null) {
      final DateTime? pickedEndDate = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: endDate ?? pickedStartDate,
        firstDate: pickedStartDate,
        lastDate: DateTime(2101),
        selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime date) {
          // Add your logic for selectable dates if needed
          return true;
        },
      );

      if (pickedEndDate != null) {
        setState(() {
          startDate = pickedStartDate;
          endDate = pickedEndDate;
        });
      }
    }
}
```

I want to select the range of dates.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYSLP.png

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/example) you can achieve range date with this.

Example :

```
SfDateRangePicker(
                onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
                selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.range,
                initialSelectedRange: PickerDateRange(
                    DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 4)),
                    DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 3))),
              ),
            )



    void _onSelectionChanged(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
      //You can handle according to your need
  setState(() {
    if (args.value is PickerDateRange) {
      _range = '${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(args.value.startDate)} -'
      // ignore: lines_longer_than_80_chars
          ' ${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(args.value.endDate ?? args.value.startDate)}';
    } else if (args.value is DateTime) {
      _selectedDate = args.value.toString();
    } else if (args.value is List<DateTime>) {
      _dateCount = args.value.length.toString();
    } else {
      _rangeCount = args.value.length.toString();
    }
  });
}
```

i hope it will help.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.